# Ionic Framework - Sass is not compiling

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass

I have an Ionic V1 app and I did `ionic setup sass`.

I've added the scss in `watchPatterns` in `ionic.config.json`. Gulp detects the file change but doesn't compile the scss into the css. Tried a lot of things.

I did `ionic setup sass` twice. It seems that the sass only compiles into css once I do `ionic setup sass`.

Here's the `gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var bower = require('bower');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sh = require('shelljs');

var paths = {
  sass: ['./scss/**/*.scss']
};

gulp.task('default', ['sass']);

gulp.task('sass', function(done) {
  gulp.src('./scss/ionic.app.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .on('error', sass.logError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .pipe(minifyCss({
      keepSpecialComments: 0
    }))
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .on('end', done);
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('install', ['git-check'], function() {
  return bower.commands.install()
    .on('log', function(data) {
      gutil.log('bower', gutil.colors.cyan(data.id), data.message);
    });
});

gulp.task('git-check', function(done) {
  if (!sh.which('git')) {
    console.log(
      '  ' + gutil.colors.red('Git is not installed.'),
      '\n  Git, the version control system, is required to download Ionic.',
      '\n  Download git here:', gutil.colors.cyan('http://git-scm.com/downloads') + '.',
      '\n  Once git is installed, run \'' + gutil.colors.cyan('gulp install') + '\' again.'
    );
    process.exit(1);
  }
  done();
});
```

Comment: Are your css changes all in ionic.app.scss ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. All changes I'd like to make I would want to put into ionic.app.scss but that file doesn't compile on watch only when I do ionic setup sass

Comment: Do you have any errors ? It doesn't compile if you do another `ionic serve` nether ?

Comment: I do ionic serve -l, though I don't think that makes a difference. And no, it doesn't compile on serve either.

Comment: Same error here...works only on "ionic setup sass".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I updated to IONIC 2 few days and have the same problem.
Just add these 2 lines to your `gulpfile.js`:

```
gulp.task('serve:before', ['default','watch']);
gulp.task('run:before', ['default']);
```

It's working for me.

Comment: Also add: gulp.task('run:before', ['default']);

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and the problem started, when I had upgraded `ionic-cli` to version 2.x. So I would suggest you to **downgrade** back to version 1.x.x.; for example I am using last subversion:

`npm install -g ionic@1.7.16`

For me, now everything works as it was before the upgrade (I am using same gulp file, I also rename "ionic.config.json" back to "ionic.project"). Hope it helps!

Comment: For latest ionic 1 version npm install -g ionic@"<2.0.0" can be used

Answer (score 1):

Check TomiL's answer, it might be able to help you. If not, try running two cmd's, first type ionic serve, and in the other one type gulp default, or whatever your task name is. here's my gulpfile

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var bower = require('bower');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sh = require('shelljs');

var paths = {
  sass: ['./scss/*.scss']
};

gulp.task('default', ['sass']);

gulp.task('sass', function(done) {
  gulp.src('./scss/ionic.app.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .on('error', sass.logError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .pipe(minifyCss({
      keepSpecialComments: 0
    }))
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .on('end', done);
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('install', ['git-check'], function() {
  return bower.commands.install()
    .on('log', function(data) {
      gutil.log('bower', gutil.colors.cyan(data.id), data.message);
    });
});

gulp.task('git-check', function(done) {
  if (!sh.which('git')) {
    console.log(
      '  ' + gutil.colors.red('Git is not installed.'),
      '\n  Git, the version control system, is required to download Ionic.',
      '\n  Download git here:', gutil.colors.cyan('http://git-scm.com/downloads') + '.',
      '\n  Once git is installed, run \'' + gutil.colors.cyan('gulp install') + '\' again.'
    );
    process.exit(1);
  }
  done();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue. I found out that it's because gulp doesn't compile scss files before 'ionic serve', so just add the task below solved the problem:

```
gulp.task('serve:before', ['default']);
```

Comment: Much thanks, just encountered that issue again, couln't remember how I solved it the first time and it was that ! thanks :D